# How to set Pycharm font colors to be same as Sublime text 3

Tags: pycharm

I have a question which I have been trying to find a solution for, I have used sublime text before and now I switched to Pycharm. I am trying to configure the text colours of Pycharm to be the same as sublime text 3 but I couldn't find anything similar or even close to it.

I need help in trying to configure the Pycharm text and theme to the same as Sublime Text 3 if there are any resources or help in this area.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 chances.

---

- Chance#1: Manually setting the sublime text colors.

---

- Pycharm -> Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Language Defaults

  ---
- Then you can set each color based on your preference

  ---

  - for instance:
  - [image]
- Chance#2: you can select one of the themes from [color-themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) website and install it.

  - For instance:
  - [image]

Comment: @Zoe Thank you for correcting my answer, appreciated.